# Issue with bootstrap navigation dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a bootstrap nav with a few custom styles, but I am unsure why the dropdown is so strange.

here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of issue]

Here is my HTML & custom CSS:

```css
nav.navbar-static-top {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background: black;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse li a {
    color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 25%;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">What you get</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The manifesto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

I can get the nav to go back to full width BUT, when I do, the navbar wont then recollapse.

To do that, I just add this to my media query:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: block;
}
```

However it is not ideal.

All I wanted to do was;

When the viewport is larger than 768px:

- center the nav items at the bottom of the navigation
- set the nav items color as white

AND

When the viewport is smaller than 768px:

- Have the navigation centered and full width (as it should be by default) when toggled to open
- Have the navigation open from the bottom of the nav (as it usually does in BS) but for some reason it is stuck to the top?

I cannot for the life of me figure it out though as my code shouldnt be affecting things in this way.

If any clarifications are needed, just ask below!

Cheers,

-- SD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to adjust some CSS rules: you shouldn't need any rules for the navbar-toggle class and you can use padding instead of height/line-height on your navbar. The `inline-block` rule is what's causing the navbar to not expand to full-width under 768px so you should insert those rules into a media query.

See working example Snippet.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  background: black;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background: black;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">How it Works</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">What you get</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">The manifesto</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">My Account</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I love you @vanburen! haha